# How can I find out the fieldname when I revieve $_FILES

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to loop through any file submissions. I can get the following aspects of the array which is sent, but I also need the fieldname as I want to add both the fieldname and the filename into a DB.

```
echo "<h2>File Uploads</h2>";
foreach($_FILES as $file){
 // echo "Fieldname: ".$file['fieldname']."<BR>";
  echo "Name: ".$file['name']."<BR>";
  echo "Type: ".$file['type']."<BR>";
  echo "Temp Name: ".$file['tmp_name']."<BR>";
  echo "Error: ".$file['error']."<BR>";
  echo "Size: ".$file['size']."<BR>";
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $file)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach for $_FILES

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
}
```

It's the key that you need.